# Author Page List - change to show authors instead of not subscribers

Tags: author

I am trying to change this code in my Authors List page template

```
$all_users = get_users();
    $allowed_users = array();
    foreach ( $all_users as $user ):
        $wp_user = new WP_User($user->ID);
        if ( !in_array( 'subscriber', $wp_user->roles ) ):
            array_push($allowed_users, $user);
        endif;
    endforeach;
```

to show only authors instead of "everyone except subscribers". I tried this:

```
if ( in_array( 'author', $wp_user->roles ) ):
```

and it does not work.

How can I change this code to show only users defined as 'author'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_users`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) has an argument that should let you select a particular role.

```
$all_users = get_users(array('role'=>'author'));
```

Should be all you need. `$all_users` should be only "Authors".